# Как быстро экпортировать огромное количество записей из базы в Excel c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, export

Имеется такой код для экспорта данных из Базы в Excel. В базе несколько тысяч записей, поэтому данный код очень тормозит. Добавляет по одной записи. И после добавления 1000 записей в один файл открывает шаблон и записывает туда еще 1000 записей, прежде сохранив старый. И еще добавления идет по листам в одном файле. 4 листа и 1000 записей в каждый из них. Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы добавление было быстрее

```
const string template = "Шаблон excel.xlsx";
            // Открываем книгу
            workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, template), 0, true);
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && i % 1000 == 0)
                {
                    workBook.SaveAs(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "\\export-data_num_" + i + ".xlsx", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                    workBook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                    if ( i != dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        k = 0;
                        workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, template), 0, true);
                    } else {
                        application.Quit();
                    }
                }
                for (int y = 0; y < dataSet11.DataTable1.Columns.Count; y++)
                {
                    if (y < 35)
                    {
                        // Получаем активную таблицу
                        worksheet = workBook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Worksheet;
                        worksheet.Cells[k + 3, y + 1].Value = dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows[i][y];
                    }
                    else if (y > 34 && y < 40)
                    {
                        worksheet = workBook.Worksheets.Item[2] as Worksheet;
                        worksheet.Cells[k + 3, y - 34].Value = dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows[i][y];
                    }
                    else if (y > 39 && y < 44)
                    {
                        worksheet = workBook.Worksheets.Item[3] as Worksheet;
                        worksheet.Cells[k + 2, y - 39].Value = dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows[i][y];
                    }
                    else if (y > 43 && y < 52)
                    {
                        worksheet = workBook.Worksheets.Item[4] as Worksheet;
                        worksheet.Cells[k + 3, y - 43].Value = dataSet11.DataTable1.Rows[i][y];

                    }

                }
                k++;
            }
```

Благодарю заранее.

Comment: А если не сохранять каждые 1к записей быстрее не становится?

Comment: Нет. Все равно одна запись добавляется долго. 
Если вывести все в массив и добавить через RANGE то все разом добавляется. Но этот вариант не позволяет мне добавить данные в другие листы. и после 1000 записей не позволяет сохранить этот файл и добавить их в другой.

Answer (score 0):

Если алгоритм изменить никак нельзя (сохранять не по 1000 записей, а по 10000 например), то попробуйте переписать так, чтобы запускалось несколько потоков, это не должно составить сложностей, так как количество записей на сохранение заранее известно, а данные сохраняются в разные файлы.